# Non-abelian bosonization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, condensed-matter, renormalization, conformal-field-theory

Reading this review about non-abelian bosonization, [Non-abelian bosonization
by I.Karmazin](http://physics.ucsd.edu/~mcgreevy/s13/final-papers/2013S-215C-Karmazin-Ivan.pdf), I stumbled about two questions

1. Below equation 6, I don't get the final point in the statement about the non-vanishing beta-function: what is the mass gap and how is it implied by the asymptotical freedom?
2. What does and mean the plot for the beta-function?

[image: plot]

Comment: Usually asymptotic freedom at high energy and strong coupling (most probably leading to confinement) at low energy are associated with negative $\beta$-function, aren't they ?

Comment: As for your questions I would recommand to have a look at the original paper by Witten.